# PDO fetch with FETCH_CLASS returns false

Tags: php, class, pdo, fetch

I have a simple class in `User.php`:

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $active;
    // Getters and setters generated by NetBeans...
}
```

My database table named `users`:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`active` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
```

And a part of my `UserDAO.php` file:

```
...
require_once './db/DBConn.php';
require_once './user/User.php';
...
public static function getById($id) {
    try {
        $db = DBConn::getInstance();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id";
        $stmt = $db->getConn()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
        var_dump($user);
        return $user;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<br/>ERROR: User fetching by ID failed!<br/>";
        return 0;
    }
}
...
```

So, when I call, let's say, `getById(1)` (or with any other valid parameter), the function executes everything and then the `var_dump($user)` outputs `bool(false)`.

If I put only `fetch()` instead of `fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User")`, the `var_dump` will give the following:

```
array(14) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "1"
  [0]=>
  string(2) "1"
  ["username"]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
  ["password"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$wTCajtRU1xXf6Z65dZYjk.mx3tClFLujshS49SvYIuGW/lDZSH3nK"
  [2]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$wTCajtRU1xXf6Z65dZYjk.mx3tClFLujshS49SvYIuGW/lDZSH3nK"
  ["email"]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(7) "John"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "John"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(13) "Johnson"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "Johnson"
  ["active"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

I have also tried with `fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,"User")`. Nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I create a `User` class instance with the `fetch`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` with fetch. You have to make a `setFetchMode()` call beforehand:

```
public static function getById($id) {
    $db = DBConn::getInstance();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt = $db->getConn()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
    $stmt->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Besides, please note that you should never catch error exceptions to report them. It makes your code dirty, unmaintainable and insecure.